# What is the Difference Between Actual and Formal Arguments in Systemverilog DPI?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vlsi

In SystemVerilog design I am using DPI-C with c program functions. While running simulation on both files, I am getting error:
"Actual type is not supported for DPI open array".
I want to know which argument is called actual and which is called formal in SystemVerilog side of DPI.

Comment: you should provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From software programming terminology, the **formal** arguments to any routine are the ones declared when defining the routine. The **actual** arguments are the expressions you pass to the routine when calling it. For example

```
import "DPI" function void master_write(int address,
                                        int data[]);
```

`address` and `data` are the **formal** arguments.

```
int addr;
int buffer[$];

always @(posedge clk) master_write(addr/2, buffer);
```

`addr/2` and `buffer` are the **actual** arguments passed to `master_write()`.

Another piece of terminology: "*not supported*" usually means what you wrote is defined by the LRM, but the tool you are using has not implemented it yet.

Comment: Error was there because of mismatching the type of formal and actual arguments now it is clear. Thanks @dave_59.